# Counting unique values throws dimension error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, unique

I have input as a pandas dataframe  `new_res` with >6m rows. My objective is to get a count of all unique rows.

```
start_hex_id_res8   start_hex_id_res9   end_hex_id_res9 end_hex_id_res9 date    is_weekday  is_holiday  starthour
0   882a100d23fffff 892a100d23bffff 892a100d237ffff 892a100d237ffff 2020-07-01  True    False   0
1   882a100d23fffff 892a100d23bffff 892a100d237ffff 892a100d237ffff 2020-07-01  True    False   0
2   882a1072c7fffff 892a1072c6bffff 892a1072187ffff 892a1072187ffff 2020-07-01  True    False   0
3   882a1072c7fffff 892a1072c6bffff 892a1072187ffff 892a1072187ffff 2020-07-01  True    False   0
4   882a100d09fffff 892a100d097ffff 892a100d09bffff 892a100d09bffff 2020-07-01  True    False   0

start_hex_id_res8    object
start_hex_id_res9    object
end_hex_id_res9      object
end_hex_id_res9      object
date                 object
is_weekday             bool
is_holiday             bool
starthour             int64
```

I have tried

```
agg = new_res.groupby(['start_hex_id_res8', 'start_hex_id_res9', 'end_hex_id_res9', 'end_hex_id_res9', 'date','is_weekday', 'is_holiday', 'starthour']).size().groupby(level=0).size()
```

but this throws an error:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'end_hex_id_res9' not 1-dimensional
```

How should I interpret this and what would the correct method be in pandas to create a new data frame that is a condensed version of `new_res`? The output would simply be a dataframe with the same column names, but with a count of all unique rows (adding a `count` column at the end).

Comment: Why do you have two columns with the same name "end_hex_id_res9"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try;

```
g=df.apply(lambda x:x.astype(str))#Make entire dataframe a str
g.groupby(list(g.columns)).ngroup().nunique()#Groupbycolumns, find special groups and see how many are unique
```

Comment: Please give me an upvote. I upvoted your question. Thanks